# Java Plugin Missing in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, jre, browser-plugin

I have JRE installed on my PC, however in chrome Java plugins are missing, it was working fine, since today, Java plugin is missing from Chrome browser.

I have installed JRE, but problem still persists.

What could be the reason and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: How have you confirmed that it is missing? Simply by trying to run Java applets or with some other method?

Comment: @gronostaj Yes, I have tried running Java applets. Getting message `This plugin is not supprted.`

Comment: @Polppan - You will have to specifically allow the old plugin style ( NPAPI ), which presents a serious security risk, if you want to enable Java.  I suggest you wait until Java extension is updated to use the more secure method.  You can enable [it](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3) if you really want.

Comment: @Ramhound How can I specifically allow old plugin NPAPI?

Comment: I already linked to how you would do it.via a group policy. Just enable the [flag](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/11/the-final-countdown-for-npapi.html).